# Can I transfer a jpeg or mjpeg file from the hard drive to the GPU's memory?

Tags: c, memory, opencl, jpeg, gpgpu

I am trying to translate single-threaded [serial code for the MJPEG decoder](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/tree/master/tima_seq_version) into OpenCL code which I want to execute on the GPU (NVIDIA Tesla k20c).

After translating several major functions into kernels, the execution time of the code has gone from about 18 ms per frame to an abysmal 400 ms per frame.

I am using a standard method of opening a file, reading it, using buffer and ndrange commands to execute code on the GPU and read the results from the CPU. **I feel that transferring the mjpeg file (which is of the data type `FILE`) to the GPU's memory will considerably cut down the communication overhead when the code is processed.**

I referred to [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/457904/move-data-to-gpu-from-hard-drive/?offset=15) but the suggestions are only applicable to CUDA. [This source](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-02-03/opencl-basics-flags-for-the-creating-memory-objects/) and NVIDIA's [OpenCL guide](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/OpenCL_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf) explain the utility of pinned memory but their usage of pinned memory is confined to kernel parameters and buffer commands.

I want to transfer the entire MJPEG file (size is about 2.8 MB) to the GPU's memory but I am struggling to find resources which do it.

Can I do this safely? If this can be done, how can I read the file to perform the various steps of MJPEG decoding?

EDIT:

The details of my GPU are as follows:

```
DEVICE_NAME = Tesla K20c
DEVICE_VENDOR = NVIDIA Corporation
DEVICE_VERSION = OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
DRIVER_VERSION = 352.21
DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS = 13
DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY = 705
DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE = 5032706048
CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT: yes
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:       local
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       48 KByte
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 64 KByte
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
```

EDIT:

Xirema has given me a fairly convincing answer.

I would greatly appreciate it if I can get suggestions for reading markers and so on after the jpeg file is on the GPU. **Are there any other ingenious tricks for reading markers more efficiently?**

Comment: Not sure how wise that is. A JPEG file has all sorts of EXIF data, copyright, exposure information, GPS data etc at the start that needs parsing serially and that doesn't lend itself to processing on a GPU - I would imagine. Try running `jhead -v SomeiPhonePicture.jpg` to see what I mean.

Comment: How do you copy the data from CPU memory to GPU memory ? Do you have some measures that show where is effectivelly the bottleneck?

Comment: @purplepsycho Which data are you referring to? I am copying the kernel parameters to the device using OpenCL's buffer commands, using ndrange to execute the kernel and then calling the resulting data from the cpu. I did profiling with the NVIDIA profiler to see that all the extra time is used to read values to and from the device.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Despite the challenges, can a jpeg file still be copied to the GPU's memory? If so, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: @a_sid I'm referring to the file data (the stuff to be decoded)

Comment: @purplepsycho I am reading the file data from the CPU by using the standard procedure of reading from files and checking markers. As of now, I am only running major functions (IDCT, iqzz and so on) on the GPU as kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from copying the literal data of the image into a buffer in host memory and then copying it to the GPU:

```
//HOST CODE
std::ifstream image_file("img.jpg", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<uint8_t> image_data;
image_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
size_t size = image_file.tellg();
image_data.resize(size);
image_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

image_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(image_data.data()), size);

cl_mem image_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size, image_data.data(), nullptr);

clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &image_buffer);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(size_t), &size);

//DEVICE CODE
kernel void image_manipulation_function(global uchar * data, size_t data_size) {
    //Go crazy.
    //Seriously.
    //(Mostly because you'd *have* to be crazy to think this is a good idea)
}
```

The only outstanding question is *why* you'd want to do this. Most image compression algorithms are poorly suited to the kind of "Embarassingly Parallel Problems" that are usually solved on GPUs, even in cases where they do adapt to multithreaded algorithms (on the order of 2-16 threads) rather nicely and efficiently. You're unlikely to make any kind of significant speed gains unless you're privy to some kind of experimental research that isn't publicly available, or if your actual task is notably esoteric.

Comment: As I said before, I think transferring the data to the GPU would trim the communication overhead. The frame processing time shot up to 170 ms for the GPU and most of it is due to the communication overhead. [JPEG Compression](http://developer.amd.com/resources/articles-whitepapers/jpeg-decoding-with-run-length-encoding-a-cpu-and-gpu-approach/) has been done using GPUs.

Comment: @a_sid If you think you have a valid use case for this kind of problem, then go right ahead with it. My code is in C++, but it should be pretty trivial to convert the host code into a C equivalent.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for reading markers(SOS, SOF and so on) **after** the image is on the GPU? Moreover, I want to transfer a mjpeg file which is of the data type `FILE`. It contains the details of the markers and so on.

Comment: @a_sid I don't know anything about the specific "under-the-hood" details of how any specific Image Compression/Expansion algorithm works. My example code is solely constrained to the question "if I have data of `x` type, can it go on the GPU?", and the answer is that it takes no more than 10 lines of code to put any lump sum of data onto the GPU. What you plan to *do* with it once it's there is outside my purview.